# Shoulda_matches error: undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Idea_3::Validations::Title:0x007f3f88fa7548>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, shoulda

I am learning TDD and trying to use shoulda_matchers to help with my testing but I get a very strange error.  Here is my test:

spec/models/idea_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Idea do

  context 'Validations' do
    describe 'title' do
       it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
    end
  end
end
```

The error on the test says:

```
Idea Validations title 
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Idea_3::Validations::Title:0x007f056f9fcdf8>
 # ./spec/models/idea_spec.rb:7:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

require 'shoulda/matchers' is at the top of my rails_helper file as per the gem instructions.

Gems I'm using:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'webmock', '~> 1.20.4'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end
```

1. ruby '2.1.2'
2. rails', '4.1.9'

Answer (score 12):

Shoulda-Matchers no longer installs itself into your test framework automatically. You need to add this to your rails_helper:

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/384), read the [note on shoulda-matchers configuration](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#configuration), and read this [blog post by maintainers](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/shoulda-matchers-3-0).

Answer (score 5):

That `require: false` in your Gemfile means the matchers aren't being loaded when you run your tests. In `rails_helper.rb` you need to add the line `require 'shoulda/matchers'` at the top.

Comment: Thanks, I have that added.

Comment: Hope it helped, did it fix your problem? If so could you please tick the answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'd already added it before I posted the question and am still having problems.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the platform for some reason mandates that you make the `shoulda-matchers` dependency optional, then you will have to add `require 'shoulda/matchers'` at the top of every test you write.

If there is no mandate, however, then elect to remove `require: false` from the Gemspec instead.

Comment: Thanks, I already have that added because the  require:false has to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with those following tips :

- in your spec :

  ```
  require 'rails_helper'
  ```
- /rails_helper

  ```
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'shoulda/matchers'
  ```
- Still in /rails_helpers, do not add :

  ```
  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :rails
    end
  end
  ```
- /gemfile

  ```
   group :development, :test do
     gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.5.0', require: false
  ```
- Do not require the gem in spec_helper

My version are different (Rails 4.2.3 and Ruby 2.3.0) but you can still test and try to adapt

Answer (score 0):

spec_helper.rb

```
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
```

rails_helper.rb

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

following the latest updated : http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v3.1.1/

in ur Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.0' 
end
```

and in the end of rails_helpers.rb

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    #with.test_framework :minitest
    #with.test_framework :minitest_4
    #with.test_framework :test_unit
    with.test_framework :rspec

    # Choose one or more libraries:
    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    with.library :action_controller
    # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

After:

```
context 'Validations' do
```

add

```
before { FactoryGirl.build(:idea) }
```